# How to update and delete object Value in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: Refer this Image]

var key = {"kay_1":{
                 "sample_1":"spmedata",
                 "sample_2":"spmedata",
        },
    "kay_2":{
                 "sample_1":"spmedata",
                 "sample_2":"spmedata",
        }
    }

Now My Question is that how to update and delete "kay_2"->"sample_1" key?

Comment: Use the dot or bracket notation to update value: `key['kay_2']['sample_1'] = 'new value'`. To delete use `delete key['kay_2']['sample_1']`.

Comment: google is your friend

Comment: Please have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Need a complete tutorial to manipulate JSON data by Native Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
var key={"kay_1":{        
             "sample_1":"spmedata",
             "sample_2":"spmedata",
    },
"kay_2":{        
             "sample_1":"spmedata",
             "sample_2":"spmedata",
    }
}

// To update the value
key['kay_2']['sample_1'] = 'new value';

// To delete the key
delete key['kay_2']['sample_1']
```

Comment: 1: Object
latlng: Object
lat: 37.579412513438385
lng: -99.4976806640625
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
2: Object
latlng: Object
lat: 37.996162679728116
lng: -90.7745361328125
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object


How to update Object '2' latlng Dynamically?
Code will check whether it is object 1 or 2?
I have integer value, I have checked it but it becomes object to integer checking?

Answer (score 1):

to update both ways could be used

```js
key.kay_2.sample_1 = "changed value";
key['kay_2']['sample_1'] = "changed value";

for delete is the same

delete key.kay_2.sample_1;
delete key['kay_2']['sample_1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the value try,

```
key.kay_2.sample_1 = "changed value";
```

To delete,

```
delete key.kay_2.sample_1
```